# What percentage of technical jobs don't require references?

Tags: united-states, references, recommendation-letter

A redditor [writes](https://old.reddit.com/r/careerguidance/comments/gddpvb/what_if_i_dont_have_references_but_i_need_to/fph60o7/):

> I’ve hired and been hired. Never have I called references if they were provided and none of mine have ever been contacted. Not sure why people ask for them since hiring is already long and expensive.

Another one [writes](https://old.reddit.com/r/careerguidance/comments/gddpvb/what_if_i_dont_have_references_but_i_need_to/fpgwja2/):

> References are overrated, I’ve never been asked about any. Worry more about your resume meshing well with the ATS and just making it past that.

What percentage of technical jobs (CS/SWE/ML/Data Scientist/etc) don't require references? It's always been my experience (which may be biased) that references are required.

(This question is about the US, since this sort of thing is probably cultural)

Comment: I haven't been able to find anyone that's done a survey on this. In my experience it varies: Some places never ask, a few places will actually ask for references up front instead of at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't related to the job, it's related to the party performing the hiring or pre-hiring screening. As such, there's no answer for this question.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but isn't the party performing the hiring a property of the job/position?

Comment: You could even be so bold as to reckon that if a position has a hiring party that doesn't require references then said position does not require references.

Comment: It is entirely at the whim of the people doing the hiring. If they want references, you'll need references. If they don't, they don't.

I give references that have an 8 hour time difference and they never get called. They got an email once but just told me what the questions are and I gave them answers, so that was just a pointless exercise.